# In PHP Form, How to hinder or suppress posting input element when its parent is hidden?

Tags: php, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid sending input fields which are hidden by display:none to a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374147/how-to-avoid-sending-input-fields-which-are-hidden-by-displaynone-to-a-server)

```
<div style="display:none;">
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

With the code above the input will be posted when the form is submitted.
But How can I avoid submitting the input element whose parent is hidden?
Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: If you are not passing, then why ur creating..if its on selection basis try to manage it via if else

Comment: I have a div element, which contains 20 input elements. I have js code, which hides the div element.

Comment: You may also refer this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008035/stop-an-input-field-in-a-form-from-being-submitted

Comment: Thank you so much for you two links Rishi. I think probably there is no direct solution.

Comment: For those who want achieve this effect, plz refer to: http://jsfiddle.net/gKsTS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While posting your form, have a `onClick` function and write below code in it. This code will help you to find all the `div` tags that is `display:none` and is the div is display:none, it will disable all the input elements.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/xyuY6/3/

```
var divs= document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i = 0;i < divs.length; i++) {
    if(divs[i].style.display == 'none') {
        if ( divs[i].hasChildNodes() ){
           var inputs = divs[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
           for(var j = 0;j < inputs.length; j++) {
               inputs[j].disabled = true;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `display:none` instead will fix your problem.

Comment: Sry man, it should be none. But even if the div is hidden, its child element input will still be passed when clicking submit button.

Comment: What about setting display:none on the input rather than the div?

Comment: Because I have 20 input elements in the div element, and I have js code, which hides the div element. add display:none to each input element is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Set `disabled` on the input element.

Comment: Because I have 20 input elements in the div element, and I have js code, which hides the div element. add display:none to each input element is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a PHP issue, it is an HTML/DOM issue.  As one person commented on your original thread, if you are generating this code via PHP, you should include `disabled='disabled'` on your input element as well to prevent submit and remove the disabled attribute when the parent element is unhidden via javascript to allow submission of element value again.

I would add HTML and Javascript tags to this answer if you want further help.

Comment: But If I have 2 divs, each of which has 20 inputs. And I have another select element containing two options: o1, o2. If I select the o1, then the second div is set hidden. If I select o2, then the first div is set hidden. I don't wanna set both div and all 20 inputs hidden. Ty for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other way what you can do is before submit, remove all child elements from the hidden divs using Javascript so that you don't get them in POST.