# Ignore Hidden Spans within Form

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a relatively simple need. I have an html form that contains a dynamic drop down that I built by using JS. When the first `select` is changed, a second (dependent) `select` appears. For example, the first `select` includes options for Ford, Toyota, and Honda. If the user selects "Ford" then another dropdown appears and allows the user to choose a model made by Ford (i.e. F150, Ranger, Fusion, etc...). I am using hidden `<span>` elements to show/hide the dependent drop downs, but the `select name` for all of the secondary drop downs is the same.

The issue is that when I submit my form, I get all three "make" variables passed through my `$_GET` method. I have included an example for clarity:

```
<span class="Ford">
    <select name="make">
        <option>F150</option>
        <option>Ranger</option>
        <option>Fusion</option>
    </select>
</span>
<span class="Toyota">
    <select name="make">
        <option>Prius</option>
        <option>Tacoma</option>
    </select>
</span>
<span class="Honda">
    <select name="make">
        <option>Civic</option>
        <option>Accord</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

The JS function just shows/hides the various `spans` as appropriate... All I want to do is pass the variable in the span that is currently showing  on the page. Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `disabled="disabled"` attribute to each hidden field, that way you will prevent them from being sent to the server.

The idea is taken from the following [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374147/how-to-avoid-sending-input-fields-which-are-hidden-by-displaynone-to-a-server)