# Prevent Forms From Submitting Based on Width

Tags: jquery, css, forms, submission

How can I prevent parts of a form on my page from submitting based on the width of the page?

i.e. if the page is between **`900px`** and **`1200px`** only form input/select items with class `.regular-form` would be included in the form submission.

Comment: You have a couple of solutions but I'd say more details are needed to fully understand how you imagine this would function.

Comment: The way your question is stated, the feature does not make sense. I'm *guessing* that this is a responsive form, and the reason you don't want those inputs submitted is because they're not visible at that width. If so, you should not duplicate the "should I display this input?" logic into "should I submit this input?" logic. Instead, use CSS media queries to show/hide them, and use JS to say "do not submit the ones that are hidden." Eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374147/how-to-avoid-sending-input-fields-which-are-hidden-by-displaynone-to-a-server This will be much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make sure that the relevant elements are not part of the DOM, and this will make sure they will also not sent in the submission.

You can use this code to do so:

```
if($(window).width() > 900 && $(window).width() < 1200) {
    $('input,select,textarea').not('.regular-form').remove()
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `not('.regular-form').remove()` according to the OP

Comment: Not a JS Master by any stretch.  So, would this be workable code?

`<script type="javascript">
    if($(window).width() > 990) {
    $('input,select,textarea').not('.regular-form').remove()
}
                                                           
    else if($(window).width() > 797 && $(window).width() < 991) {
    $('input,select,textarea').not('.shorter-form').remove()
} else {

}
                                                           
                                                           
</script>`

Comment: Remove the `type="javascript"`. you don't need it. And the syntax looks ok. Don't forget to include the jquery library (and I think you are missing some of the width values, for example 990). Try it and update.

Comment: Yes for sure.  Thanks for taking the time to answer and for confirming my code as well.  Much much appreciate it!

Comment: Hey Dekel.  To clarify...  Isn't this script removing ALL input, select and textareas if those text areas are NOT .regular-form?  So that if the script shows up on another page of the site and there are other form elements on that page those will be removed from the page?  If so, how would I make sure it ONLY removes the .shorter-form and the .shortest-form items?

Comment: This will first find all the `input,select,textarea` elements. Then - for each and every one of them - if it is not a `.refular-form` - it will delete it from the page.

Comment: Ok, so that is actually a problem then as it is deleting elements I don't want deleting.  The class of the entire form is .thequickie so I tried this : `$( '.thequickie' ).children('input,select,textarea').not('.regular-form').remove(); ` but it isn't working.  Does it look right to you? Basically I am only wanting to remove elements WITHIN that form ONLY that are not regular-form.

Comment: Create an example of the form, the buttons, the elements and add a link in an comment. You can use http://jsfiddle.net for that

Comment: Roger that!  Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/nk4Lyu9w/  In this case, the current JS will ALSO remove the second form on that page (and another other forms on any page the JS exists.)  So, I want to make sure that it ONLY applies to the forms within that search bar.

Comment: I don't see where you used there the code from the comments (the part with `.thequickie`)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ebgv2m1c/5/  Doesn't use the term quickie, but uses .main-form instead.  Same idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132336/discussion-between-craig-and-dekel).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need to account for the window being dynamically resized or not, so a simple solution would be something like this:

```
if($(window).width() > 900 && $(window).width() < 1200)
{
    $('.regular-form').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

Comment: @Dekel why is that? Seems to me it should. https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled