# How to include my hidden form fields in the form querystring?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form that I am doing a METHOD="GET" on, so I want the form to make a HTTP request with the form fields as querystring values.

I have some hidden form fields, and when I click a button I wanted the form to be posted to:

```
/some/path?a=1&b=2
```

But because the form fields were hidden they don't get included.

I then changed the input type to text, but did a display:none on each one, and the same thing happens.

If I change the action URL to include querystring values, those also get ignored.

How can I get this too work?
I want clicking a button to include the querystring values in the form http GET request.

Comment: This is a known topic Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374147/how-to-avoid-sending-input-fields-which-are-hidden-by-displaynone-to-a-server

Comment: Do the hidden fields have a name attribute on them?  They must have a name attribute on them to be included in the normal form submit logic.

Comment: @headmax that thread is about inputs being sent and wanting to ignore them.  This thread is about them not being sent and wanting to include them.  It's the reverse case.

Comment: @Taplar ok didn't really show :(, why this inputs is named as hidden ...