# jquery returning multiple select as array in php and not inputting the correct value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So this is my html and this subjects has 5 select with the same names because it hides and show depending on the value selected by the user

```
<div class="formcontent" >
    <select  class="browser-default custom-select form-control" name="subject" id="subject" autocomplete="off">
      <option >Please Choose A Subject</option>
      <option class="language" value="language">Language</option>
      <option class="Humanities_and_Communication" value="Humanities_and_Communication">Humanities and Communication</option>
      <option class="Science" value="Science">Science</option>
      <option class="SOC_Science" value="SOC_Science">SOC_Science</option>
      <option class="PHYSICAL_EDUCATION" value="PHYSICAL_EDUCATION">P.E</option>
    </select>
    </div>
<div class="formcontent subsubjects language mt-4 "  name="language" >
    <select class="browser-default custom-select subsubjects form-control" id="language" name="subjects" autocomplete="off">
      <option >Please Choose  A Sub Subject</option>
      <option value="KOMUNIKASYON AT PANANALIKSIK">KOMUNIKASYON AT PANANALIKSIK</option>
      <option value="ORAL COMMUNICATION">ORAL COMMUNICATION</option>
      <option value="SA WIKA AT KULTURANG PILIPPINO">SA WIKA AT KULTURANG PILIPPINO</option>
      <option value="READING ANG WRITING">READING ANG WRITING</option>
      <option value="TEKSTO TUNGO SA PANANALIKSIK">TEKSTO TUNGO SA PANANALIKSIK</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="formcontent subsubjects Humanities_and_Communication mt-4 " name="Humanities_and_Communication" id="Humanities_and_Communication">
    <select class="browser-default custom-select subsubjects form-control" id="" name="subjects" autocomplete="off">
      <option >Please Choose  A Sub Subject</option>
      <option value="21ST CENTURY LITERATURE FROM THE PHILIPPINES AND THE WORLD">21ST CENTURY LITERATURE FROM THE PHILIPPINES AND THE WORLD</option>
      <option value="CONTEMPORARY PHILIPPINES ATRS FROM THE REGION">CONTEMPORARY PHILIPPINES ATRS FROM THE REGION</option>
      <option value="MEDIA AND INFORMATION LITERACY">MEDIA AND INFORMATION LITERACY</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="formcontent subsubjects Mathematics mt-4 "  name="Mathematics">
    <select  class="browser-default custom-select subsubjects form-control" id="Mathematics" name ='subjects'id="" autocomplete="off">
      <option >Please Choose  A Sub Subject</option>
      <option value="GENERAL MATHEMATICS">GENERAL MATHEMATICS</option>
      <option value="STATISTIC AND PROBABILITY">STATISTIC AND PROBABILITY</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="formcontent subsubjects Science mt-4 "  name="Science">
    <select  class="browser-default custom-select subsubjects form-control" id="Science" name="subjects" autocomplete="off">
      <option >Please Choose  A Sub Subject</option>
      <option value="EARTH SCIENCE">EARTH SCIENCE</option>
      <option value="EARTH AND LIFE SCIENCE">EARTH AND LIFE SCIENCE</option>
      <option value="PHYSICAL SCIENCE">PHYSICAL SCIENCE</option>
      <option value="DISASTER READINESS AND RISK REDUCTION ">DISASTER READINESS AND RISK REDUCTION </option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="formcontent subsubjects SOC_Science mt-4 "  name="SOC_Science">
    <select  class="browser-default custom-select subsubjects form-control " id="SOC_Science"  name="subjects" autocomplete="off">
      <option >Please Choose  A Sub Subject</option>
      <option value="PERSONAL DEVELOPMENT">PERSONAL DEVELOPMENT</option>
      <option value="UNDERSTANDING CULTURE SOCIENTY AND POLITICS">UNDERSTANDING CULTURE SOCIENTY AND POLITICS</option>
      <option value="INTRODUCTION TO PHILOSOPHY OF THE HUMAN PERSON">INTRODUCTION TO PHILOSOPHY OF THE HUMAN PERSON</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="formcontent subsubjects PHYSICAL_EDUCATION mt-4 " name="PE">
    <select  class="browser-default custom-select subsubjects form-control" id="PHYSICAL_EDUCATION" name="subjects" autocomplete="off" >
      <option >Please Choose  A Sub Subject</option>
      <option value="PHYSICAL EDUCATION">PHYSICAL EDUCATION</option>
      <option value="HEALTH 1">HEALTH 1</option>
      <option value="HEALTH 2">HEALTH 2</option>
      <option value="HEALTH 3">HEALTH 3</option>
      <option value="HEALTH 4">HEALTH 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This code hide and changes the mentiond select tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subject').change(function(){
        $('#subsubjects').hide();
        $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

and this is my javascript but this javascript returns as like this in my php query and the selected value shows but in my database the please choose a subject was selected and its not the value, How can I overcome this?

```
0   KOMUNIKASYON+AT+PANANALIKSIK
1   Please+Choose+A+Sub+Subject
2   Please+Choose+A+Sub+Subject
```

```
function subjCode() {


  $('#subjectForm').unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
    var setValue = $('#subjectcode').val(Math.random().toString(36).substring(7));
    var subject = $('#subject option:selected').val();
    var subsubject = $('#subsubject option:selected').val();
    var date = $("#datecreated").val(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));

    if (subject == "") {
      $("#ps-msg").html("Please Enter A subject");
      $(".lead").html("OOPS!");
      $('#prompt-warning').modal('show');
    }

    if (subjeccode == "") {
      $("#ps-msg").html(" Sub Subject cannot be generated");
      $(".lead").html("OOPS!");
      $('#prompt-warning').modal('show');
    }

    if (subject && setValue && date) {
      var form = $(this);
      var formData = new FormData(this);
      $(".formcontent").hide();
      $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
          if (response.success == true) {
            $("#subjectForm")[0].reset();
            $(".formcontent").show();
            $("#pw-msg").html(response.messages);
            $(".lead").html("SUCCESS");
            $('#prompt-success').modal('show');
          } // if
          else if (response.success == false) {
            $(".formcontent").show();
            $("#pw-msg").html(response.messages);
            $(".lead").html("OOPS!");
            $('#prompt-warning').modal('show');
          } // if
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $(".formcontent").show();
          $("#ps-msg").html("CONNECTION ERROR, TRY AGAIN.");
          $(".lead").html("OOPS!");
          $('#prompt-warning').modal('show');
        }
      });

    }
    return false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple selects with `id="subsubjects"`? IDs should be unique.

Comment: `bind()` and `unbind()` have been deprecated, you should use `on()` and `off()`.

Comment: `var subject = $('#subject option:selected').val();` can be written more simply as `var subject = $('#subject').val();`

Comment: @Barmar no only the names are repeated not the ids

Comment: When you use `.val()` with an argument, it sets the value but returns the element, not the new value.

Comment: You can't have two `data:` options in the same `$.ajax()` call. One of them will be ignored.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the HTML of the form?

Comment: All inputs are submitted, not just the ones that are showing.

Comment: @Barmar I updated the html

Comment: See [How to avoid submitting inputs that are hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374147/how-to-avoid-sending-input-fields-which-are-hidden-by-displaynone-to-a-server)

Comment: @Barmar my only problem is the name = "subjects" because it is returning all the value from the .hide() function not the only one I selected. It is returning as array

Comment: I don't see how you could be getting all the values. It should only get the last one. You would get an array if you have `name="subjects[]"`.

Comment: @Barmar 0   KOMUNIKASYON+AT+PANANALIKSIK
1   Please+Choose+A+Sub+Subject
2   Please+Choose+A+Sub+Subject those are returning in the browser form data

Comment: That's correct, the form data sends all of them. But in PHP, `$_POST['subjects']` will just be the last one.

Comment: yes and the value is not inserting nothing is inserting only the optopn please choose a sub subject, that $_POST['subjects'] is connected to 5 select since 5 of this is availabe name = 'subjects',

Comment: Shouldn't `$('#subsubjects').hide();` be `$('.subsubjects').hide();`? You don't have `id="subsubjects"` anywhere.

Comment: Did you read the question I linked to? Hiding the DIV doesn't prevent it from sending the input. You have to disable the input as well.

Comment: `$(".subsubjects select").prop("disabled", true); $("." + this.value + " select").prop("disabled", false);`

Comment: @Barmar where will i input that?

Comment: @Barmar its not functioning anymore after i inserted your correction sorry

Comment: Make sure you have a space after the quote in `$("." + this.value + " select")`

Comment: @Barmar thankyou so much! thankyou for your fix, but anyway after the submit was click all is well but all hidden showed, can you give me an idea?

Comment: You shouldn't change the code that hides the inputs, just add this in addition.

Comment: @Barmar yes I didnt change the code but after submitting the form all hidden divs was shown

Comment: I can't see any reason for that. Make sure you're not getting an error.